# Efficient methods for flagging profile submissions from a contact form

Tags: wordpress, profile, jquery

Running Wordpress 4.8 and CiviCRM 4.7.19

As per a suggestion elsewhere on the forum, I created a profile for use on our 'Contact us' page (email, first name, last name, message as a multi-record listing).  I'm trying to figure out the best way to mark/flag/indicate each new submission, so staff will be aware of needing to response and can indicate when a response has been sent for the specific issue.  Right now, my thought is to create a custom yes/no field marked as "triage" that automatically gets set to 'yes' when a form is submitted, and can be set back to 'no' by our staff once the question has been addressed.  From there, I figured we'd create a query for all triage=yes entries and have it appear on the Civi dashboard.  From what I've read, this field could be included in the profile but hidden from the end user with Jquery.

Is there a better way to handle this in Civi?  I'm only beginning to use the software and don't know if some use of tags, groups, or another tool is a more sensible path than the one I've mentioned.

Thanks all,

Comment: I don't think there is yet a way to have Activities created from Profiles in WP. Activities are certainly geared to what you want as they get assigned to people with due dates etc. Those using Drupal can use Webforms to do this, since

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution to use a hidden field seems reasonable. I would suggest though, instead, you create a custom field (on the same dataset) called Triaged, with a default of 'No' (or null).

Don't even bother including it on the Profile.

Then when the contact us profile is manually processed, the staff member checks the Triaged field (or sets it to Yes) on the backend.

No jquery needed (there still are some people that don't have javascript enabled). Let the system do the most it can for you.

As @petednz points out, Drupal users have a way to handle this using Webforms. If you are ambitious, you could build a form on the WordPress side and on its submission run a bit of PHP code to call the CiviCRM API to do what you need it to.  But that's way more technical than most people want.

Comment: Dave - thanks for the quick reply.

With the first suggestion you give, what do you think would be the best way to handle a single person using the contact form multiple times?  I feel like I'd still want the form to reset the status of Triaged back to a 'No' as an indicator of a new message.

Good call on avoiding JS if possible ; the less I can engineer this, the better.

Comment: Simple, you already are putting the message in a multi-record dataset.... just put the Triaged field in the same dataset.

Comment: Yep, you've got it.  I didn't realize I could pass a value through without having it on the form.  As an aside for anyone ending up in this stack needing to hide a form element, we did try hiding a variable with CSS easily enough (e.g. #editrow-custom_<insert line here> { visibility: hidden; })